# Icons disappearing in PopUp menu VB6

Tags: api, menu, vb6, popup, icons

Icons disappearing in PopUp menu after setting the main (first) PopUp menu item Visible property to False, but they come back when Visible property switched back to Enable, why?

```
Option Explicit

Private Const MF_BITMAP = &H4&
Private Const MF_BYPOSITION  As Long = &H400& '&H404&

Private Declare Function GetMenu Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetSubMenu Lib "user32" (ByVal hMenu As Long, ByVal nPos As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function SetMenuItemBitmaps Lib "user32" (ByVal hMenu As Long, ByVal nPosition As Long, ByVal wFlags As Long, ByVal hBitmapUnchecked As Long, ByVal hBitmapChecked As Long) As Long

Public Sub SetPopUpMenuIcons(objFRM As Form)
 On Error Resume Next

 Dim lgRet As Long
 Dim lgMnu As Long
 Dim lgSubMnu As Long

 lgMnu = GetMenu(objFRM.hwnd)

 lgSubMnu = GetSubMenu(lgMnu, 0)

 With objFRM
  lgRet = SetMenuItemBitmaps(lgSubMnu, 0, MF_BYPOSITION, .imgMnu(0).Picture, 0)
  lgRet = SetMenuItemBitmaps(lgSubMnu, 1, MF_BYPOSITION, .imgMnu(1).Picture, 0)
  lgRet = SetMenuItemBitmaps(lgSubMnu, 2, MF_BYPOSITION, .imgMnu(2).Picture, 0)
  lgRet = SetMenuItemBitmaps(lgSubMnu, 3, MF_BYPOSITION, .imgMnu(3).Picture, 0)
  lgRet = SetMenuItemBitmaps(lgSubMnu, 4, MF_BYPOSITION, .imgMnu(4).Picture, 0)
 End With

 Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the VB6 PopupMenu method actually creates a new popup menu (by calling CreatePopupMenu) and then uses the hidden menu items as templates for creating items via InsertMenu or AppendMenu, but without using the bitmap flag and handles which it doesn't know you added behind its back.

You might have to do all of the work yourself, calling CreatePopupMenu and then InsertMenuItem instead of InsertMenu/AppendMenu for each item (in order to have both a bitmap and text), and use subclassing to get the selection "event" if any, and so on.

In other words there may be no trivial way to do what you want.  The VB6 menu plumbing seems to be based on old 16-bit Windows (Win 3.x) logic and API calls.

Too bad we never got a real VB7!  Microsoft had accumulated a vast list of such feature enhancements before pulling the plug in favor of .Net.

There may be a 3rd party menu control that could make this easier.